# How to add a link to the full source code with sphinx-doc?

Tags: python-sphinx

I wrote a documentation with python-sphinx and I use the `sphinx.ext.viewcode` extension in order to link part of the documentation to the corresponding source code.

How can I add a link to that page but without hilighting something ?